# Meteor install Android SDK API 10 for 2.3.4

Tags: android, meteor

I want to create an app with Meteor for Android 2.3.4 and higher. I wanted to use API 10, but when I executed:

```
meteor install-sdk android
```

It installed API 19. What can I do to get API 10 with Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to install an old API, or do you just want to build against API 10 as a target? (The latter is, I believe, the more common practice.)

If so, I think you can just add `App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '10');` to your `mobile-config.js`.